# PHP Undefined index: on line

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I am passing arguments to a PHP webservice like this:

```
localhost/webservice1.php?method=browse&reg=001&name=john
```

But it gives the `Notice Undefined Index: method`

My PHP code is like this:

```
$methd = $_POST['method'];

if($methd=="save")
    save();

if($methd=="signup")
    signup();

if($methd=="browse")
    browse();
```

Comment: `$methd = $_POST['method'];` should be `$methd = $_GET['method'];`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+Notice+Undefined+Index%3A+method - It's a very common error

Comment: $_GET works very fine, but $_GET is not working when i pass the arguments from the android device

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable"  and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters in the query string are accessed with the $_GET array, so use

```
$method = $_GET['method'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the $_GET[] superglobal rather than $_POST since you're passing arguments in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use the $_GET method instead of the $_POST

Answer (score 0):

Url parameters are passed through $_GET